# How change product name in admin orders prestashop

Tags: list, prestashop

I have problem with old prestashop.
[image]

Wants to do to the name of the product is in the form of a list
attribute
br
attribute
br
...

```
<td><a href="index.php?tab=AdminCatalog&id_product='.$product['product_id'].'&updateproduct&token='.$tokenCatalog.'">
                                    <span class="productName">'.$product['product_name'].'</span><br />
                                    '.($product['product_reference'] ? $this->l('Ref:').' '.$product['product_reference'] : '')
                                    .(($product['product_reference'] AND $product['product_supplier_reference']) ? ' / '.$product['product_supplier_reference'] : '')
                                    .'</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the top of your file :

```
$product_name = $product['product_name']
$pos = strpos($product_name, ' - ');
if($pos !== false) {
    $product_name = substr_replace($product_name, '<br />', $pos, 3);
}
$product_name = str_replace(', ', '<br />', $product_name);
```

We replace the first `' - '` and each `', '` by a `<br />` so each attributes are on a single line.

Then you can use `$product_name` instead of `$product['product_name']` in your code :

```
<td><a href="index.php?tab=AdminCatalog&id_product='.$product['product_id'].'&updateproduct&token='.$tokenCatalog.'">
                                    <span class="productName">'.$product_name.'</span><br />
                                    '.($product['product_reference'] ? $this->l('Ref:').' '.$product['product_reference'] : '')
                                    .(($product['product_reference'] AND $product['product_supplier_reference']) ? ' / '.$product['product_supplier_reference'] : '')
                                    .'</a></td>
```